# Getting out a undefined number of ViewController from an Array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, object, nsarray

In my app, I load UIViewController into an array from a .plist, and then, I need to get those VC's out.  The problem is, since the number of VC's is not always the same, then I don't know how many I'm getting out each time.  So I'm looking for a better engeneered solution - better iteration, rather than hard coding.

For example:

```
NSMutableArray *views = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = [currentList count]; i > 0; i--) {
    UIViewController *view = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    view.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"dgdg - %i", i];
    [views addObject:view];
}
```

So there is my array of VC's, and now:

```
   myIvar = [[CustomSubClass alloc] initWithViewControllers:**help** nil];
```

I tried:

```
   myIvar = [[CustomSubClass alloc] initWithViewControllers:[views copy], nil];
```

and:

```
   myIvar = [[CustomSubClass alloc] initWithViewControllers:[NSIndexSet..., nil];
```

I tried:

```
   myIvar = [[CustomSubClass alloc] initWithViewControllers:[views objectAtIndex:0]... nil];
```

but none of it worked. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you want is like this:

```
[[CustomSubClass alloc] initWithViewControllers:[views objectAtIndex:0], [views objectAtIndex:1], [views objectAtIndex:2], nil];
```

Basically just repeat have all your arguments separated by commas, then always have the final argument be nil.

Comment: The problem with that is sometimes it might be 8 items, sometimes it might be 20.  So I'm looking for a way the computer can see the number of items and then put the proper number, rather then hard coding

Answer (score 0):

views is an array and you can pass this directly as a parameter like so:

```
 myIvar = [[CustomSubClass alloc] initWithViewControllers:views];
```